# Sharepoint VBA ADODB update statement not working

Tags: vba, sharepoint, adodb

While using VBA to update a certain record in a SharePoint list, the program is stuck at update command or a at certain field

Code:

```
JRVCS = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=0;RetrieveIds=Yes;DATABASE=https://sites.123.com/sites/abc/def/;LIST=" 
JRVList = JRVCS & "{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXX};"
        
Set JRVConn = New ADODB.Connection Set JRVRSet = New ADODB.Recordset
With JRVConn
   .ConnectionString = JRVList
   .Open 
End With
        
mySQL = "SELECT * FROM [List1] WHERE [ID] = 200;"
        
JRVRSet.Open mySQL, JRVConn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
        
If Not (JRVRSet.BOF And JRVRSet.EOF) Then
   JRVRSet.Fields("Feild 1") = "Value 1"
   JRVRSet.Fields("Date") = CDate(Now() + 1)
   JRVRSet.Update 
End If
        
If CBool(JRVRSet.State And adStateOpen) = True Then JRVRSet.Close: Set JRVRSet = Nothing 
If CBool(JRVConn.State And adStateOpen) = True Then JRVConn.Close: Set JRVConn = Nothing
```

In above program the program is stuck at *JRVRSet.Fields("Date") = CDate(Format(Now() + 1))* and *JRVRSet.Update*.

This issue is occurring in certain SharePoint sites only. In a SharePoint site which I created, this code works perfectly. Is this related to permission?

Comment: Could be a problem with the date format. When your field `"Date"` is a real date field, you probably should write a date in it, not a string? Your statement `CDate(Format(Now() + 1))` looks strange anyhow, `Format` returns a string, makes no sense to use `CDate` to convert that to a string.

Comment: Apologies, that was a type, i removed format function and it didn't work. The excel is stuck at that line

Comment: "The excel is stuck at that line" - what does that mean exactly?  Are you getting an error message or ????

Comment: There is no error message, the interpreter does not proceed ahead of record set update statement